# recvmsg() randomly returns EWOULDBLOCK

Tags: c, sockets

I have a TCP client/server program set that has been running for 10+ years without problems.  The 'head' job spawns a body of child processes (I am on the AS400 platform which does not support fork()/exec()).  The head job sets itself up as a TCP server and as soon as a connection comes in, it immediately gives away the connection to one of the child jobs via sendmsg().  The usual pattern of socketpair(), etc is used.  I admit that when I was piecing this all together 12 years ago, I didn't understand everything that was going on.  The code I found to pass an open connection is below.  So, the head job is waiting on accept() and calling sendfd() when accept() returns.

```
int sendfd(int s, int fd)
{
    char buf[1];
    struct iovec iov;
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct cmsghdr *cmsg;
    int n;
    char cms[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(int))];

    buf[0] = 0;
    iov.iov_base = buf;
    iov.iov_len = 1;

    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof msg);
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_control = (caddr_t)cms;
    msg.msg_controllen = CMSG_LEN(sizeof(int));

    cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
    cmsg->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(sizeof(int));
    cmsg->cmsg_level = SOL_SOCKET;
    cmsg->cmsg_type = SCM_RIGHTS;
    memmove(CMSG_DATA(cmsg), &fd, sizeof(int));

    if ((n = sendmsg(s, &msg, 0)) != iov.iov_len) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, the child jobs run a routine to receive the connection.  It is below.  The pool of child processes effectively run this routine like "recvfd(0);"  Our QA dept will get an automated test going and as of last week, the entire body of child processes will die, seemingly randomly, down to the second, with EWOULDBLOCK.  I am confused by this error.  recvmsg() is always blocking, waiting for a message.  Is the error pertain to the socket that is being received, or the "0" that it is being used to receive on?  Nothing in my code is changing the qualities of file descriptor 0. I am really befuddled on why the entire body of child processes dies.  Something tells me the 0 file descriptor is being changed, but there is nothing in the code for either program that does any manipulation like this.

```
int recvfd(int s)
{
    int ret, fd;
    char buf[1];
    struct iovec iov;
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct cmsghdr *cmsg;
    char cms[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(int))];

    iov.iov_base = buf;
    iov.iov_len = 1;

    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof msg);
    msg.msg_name = 0;
    msg.msg_namelen = 0;
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

    msg.msg_control = (caddr_t)cms;
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof cms;

    if ((ret = recvmsg(s, &msg, 0)) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (ret == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
    memmove(&fd, CMSG_DATA(cmsg), sizeof(int));

    return fd;
}
```

I can post more code if more detail is needed.  I have to find this bug right away as it is the core of our business.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  Here is a snippet from the child code.  See that 'worker_sd' is explicitly set to 0.  A problem I need to fix is that exiting the loop means exiting the program, but I don't know if there is a way to handle this error.

The error message eventually will be:
**Transaction child is exiting with new_sock=-1 and error=Operation would have caused the process to be suspended.**

```
// worker_sd is explicitly set to 0 because the parent set the child's 0 file descriptor (the usual one
// reserved for standard input) to be the socket over which open descriptors come.
int worker_sd = 0;

jobSwitches.get();
logging_on = jobSwitches[QQJobSwitches::LOGGING_ON] == '1';
debug_on = jobSwitches[QQJobSwitches::DEBUG_ON] == '1';
wait_on_child_process = jobSwitches[QQJobSwitches::WAIT_ON_CHILD] == '1';

if (debug_on) {
    CERR << "START:  Waiting for a message..." << endl;
}
while ((new_sock = recvfd(worker_sd)) >= 0) {
    stringstream sstr;
    string ip_str, port_str;
    bool success;
```

Comment: So this application worked for 10+ years and now you see new behavior? Has the code changed? Any updates to the OS, libraries, system settings etc that you know about that would change your codes behavior?

Comment: MCVE please. Where would EWOULDBLOCK come from? For starters, I would improve error handling in this piece of code, so that it would be clearer where the error is coming from.

Comment: @Chimera, it was worked without problems.  No real code changes recently. 
 Certainly I am looking at system-related possibilities, but since this has started happening, we've found nothing (yet).  I am adding more logging code at this moment.  I am also doing some research with getsockopt() that might tell me a better story.

Comment: @SergeyA.  I feel certain that recvmsg() in the recvfd() routine is causing the problem.  I am adding more logging code at the moment.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: The only way that `recvmsg()` can report `EWOULDBLOCK` is if either 1) `s` is a non-blocking socket and there is no data waiting to be read when `recvmsg()` is called, or 2) `s` is a blocking socket with a receive timeout assigned and `recvmsg()` times out before any data is received. What logic are you using to determine when `recvfd()` should be called? Are you using `select()` or `(e)poll()` at all? Are you sure that `s` is actually referring to the correct socket that you are expecting to read from?

Comment: This might be helpful? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzab6/rzab6.pdf

Comment: I echo @RemyLebeau comment. Are you using `select()` or `poll()` to determine if the socket has data to be read?

Comment: @Chimera Admittedly I'm not.  It's never needed it before and you can run things through this all day and it won't happen until later or it may happen right away.  *something* has changed - not sure what yet.  Thanks.

Comment: @KellyBeard - you should be using `select` at least to determine if the socket actually has data ready to be read to avoid the EWOULDBLOCK problem.

Comment: @Chimera Understood, but theoretically I shouldn't need to because fd 0 is a blocking socket.  I'm putting more logging statements in and a call to fcntl() to see if the blocking status has changed somehow.   I will put a select() in though.